# Chrome not displaying the image drawn on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I am trying to display some objects drawn on the canvas.
It works fine in the firefox but in chrome the image is drawn under the canvas.

In my case the there is an image on the top of canvas on which I am trying to draw some shapes.

Please help.

```
   <SCRIPT>
    var oImageBuffer = document.createElement('img');


    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("semiAutoAdjustments").style.visibility = "hidden";
        checkProgress();

        setCanvas("ImageResultsCanvas");

        CanvasUtils.ImageBuffer = oImageBuffer;
        CanvasUtils.URLPrefix = "${ctx}/project/image?id=";
        CanvasUtils.LongAxis = 440;
        CanvasUtils.ShortAxis = 330;

        populateRecipes();

        changeCanvasImage("${selectedImageID}");                   
        InstantiateProcessedImage();

        setProcessedImage(m_oProcessedImage);
        RepaintCanvas();
    });

    function InstantiateProcessedImage()
    {
        <c:if test="${not empty selectedProcessImage.toogleProcessedImage}">
             var l_lImageId = "${selectedProcessImage.toogleProcessedImage.imageId}";
          var imageName = "${selectedProcessImage.toogleProcessedImage.imageName}";
             var i=0;var d=0;

             m_oProcessedImage = new ProcessedImage();
          m_oProcessedImage.ImageID = l_lImageId;

          var l_aJSMeasurements = new Array();
           <c:forEach var="measItem" varStatus="status" items="${selectedProcessImage.toogleProcessedImage.measurements}"> 
                var l_oMeasurement = new Measurement();
                 l_oMeasurement.Name = "${measItem.name}";
                 l_oMeasurement.Value = ${measItem.value};
                 l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints = new Array();
                 <c:forEach var="definingPointsItem" varStatus="cnt" items="${measItem.definingPoints}"> 
                     l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints[${cnt.index}] = new Pixel();
                     l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints[${cnt.index}].x = ${definingPointsItem.x};
                     l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints[${cnt.index}].y = ${definingPointsItem.y};
                 </c:forEach>
                 l_aJSMeasurements.push(l_oMeasurement);     
            </c:forEach>



            m_oProcessedImage.Measurements = l_aJSMeasurements;

            var l_aJSMeasurementBoxes = new Array();
         <c:forEach var="measBoxItem" varStatus="meanBoxCnt" items="${selectedProcessImage.toogleProcessedImage.measuredBoxes}"> 

                var l_oMeasuredImageBox = new MeasuredImageBox(); 
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region = new Box();
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region.UL = new Pixel();
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region.LR = new Pixel();
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region.UL.x = ${measBoxItem.region.ul.x};
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region.UL.y = ${measBoxItem.region.ul.y};
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region.LR.x = ${measBoxItem.region.lr.x};
                l_oMeasuredImageBox.Region.LR.y = ${measBoxItem.region.lr.y};

                l_oMeasuredImageBox.LayerBottoms = ${measBoxItem.layerBottoms};

                 l_oMeasuredImageBox.Measurements = new Array();
                  <c:forEach var="measFromMeasBoxItem" varStatus="measFromMeasBoxItemCnt" items="${selectedProcessImage.toogleProcessedImage.measuredBoxes[meanBoxCnt.index].measurements}"> 
                     var l_oMeasurement = new Measurement();
                     l_oMeasurement.Name = "${measFromMeasBoxItem.name}";
                     l_oMeasurement.Value = ${measFromMeasBoxItem.value};
                     l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints = new Array();
                     <c:forEach var="measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItem" varStatus="measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItemCnt" items="${measFromMeasBoxItem.definingPoints}"> 
                        l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints[${measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItemCnt.index}] = new Pixel();
                        l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints[${measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItemCnt.index}].x = ${measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItem.x};
                        l_oMeasurement.DefiningPoints[${measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItemCnt.index}].y = ${measDefPtsFromMeasBoxItem.y};
                    </c:forEach>
                    l_oMeasuredImageBox.Measurements.push(l_oMeasurement);
                 </c:forEach>
                 l_aJSMeasurementBoxes.push(l_oMeasuredImageBox);

             </c:forEach>
             m_oProcessedImage.MeasuredBoxes = l_aJSMeasurementBoxes;

        </c:if>

    }

    function ProcessedImageFromDTO(p_oProcessImageDTO) {
        var l_oProcessedImage = new ProcessedImage();
        l_oProcessedImage.MeasuredBoxes = new Array();
        for (var iBox=0; iBox<p_oProcessImageDTO.measurementList.length; ++iBox) {

        }


        return l_oProcessedImage;
    }

    function getResults4Image(obj)
    {
        //alert(obj.id);
        var imageId = obj.id;
        //get selected recipe name
        var l_iSelectedRecipeIndex = document.getElementById("RecipeNameOptionsCB").selectedIndex
        var recipeName = document.getElementById("RecipeNameOptionsCB").children[l_iSelectedRecipeIndex].text;
        //refresh the page.
        getResults(imageId, recipeName);
    }




    function getResults(imageId, recipeName)
    {
        window.location.href = "${ctx}/viewer/processedImageResults?recipeName=" + recipeName + "&imageId=" + imageId;

    }

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I really won't read that much code ... please shorten the code down and only leave things important to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam I have updated the code. I am trying to display the object on the image first instead on the canvas directly.

Comment: Would you mind showing us the output instead of the serverside logic/output mix?